# Как сортировать строки без учета регистра в postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, сортировка

Как сортировать строки без учета регистра в postgresql? Желательно не использовать тип данных CITEXT. Пробовал `ORDER BY LOWWER(colname)`, не сработало.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать разные `COLLATE` с `ORDER BY`

```
select * from users order by nick COLLATE "default";
 
select * from users order by nick COLLATE "C";
```

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=41ea003e22d3e6bf810ddb779987375b&php_version=null&sql_version=psql13)

Comment: CILLATE не работает с utf, такую ошибку выдает постгрес